# Why does python datetime.timestamp(0) return 1AM as opposed to 00:00

Tags: python, unix-timestamp

According to the definition of [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), it measures the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00 UTC on January 1st 1970. However, when I run `datetime.fromtimestamp(0)` using python 3.8, I get `1970-01-01 01:00:00`. Why is it 1AM and not 00:00?

Comment: Timezones. For me it returns 11:00 :)

Comment: I see, it has second argument. Lol I thought it was UTC by default

Comment: Try `datetime.utcfromtimestamp` if you want UTC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timezones!!!

Try this:

```
from datetime import *
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(0, timezone.utc))
```

This gets the epoch time in UTC (+00:00)

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the documentation of [datetime.fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)

> Return the **local** date and time corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is returned by time.time().

(Emphasis mine)

Is your computer running on CET?

Comment: Indeed it is CET, my bad